# Make proper synchronisation in singleton

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a question regarding synchronisation. I have one single instance of:

`

```
@Service
public class MyService {

   //if singleton - should this map be static?
   private static Map<String, String> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

 public String put(String value) {
    if (!cache.containsKey(value)) {
       String newValue = someRandomString();
        cache.put(value, newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
    return cache.get(value);
 }

public String get(String value) {
   return cache.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(value))
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
  .findFirst().get();
}

}
```

The question is - how to make proper synchronisation in case of singleton and many threads calling the service. Seems like both methods are affected and sometimes no appropriate data can be calculated/put into map for the same String values. Is ConcurrentHashMap to be replaced by SynchronizedMap? Should I make a synchronized block in both methods?

Comment: It's pretty misleading that `value` is the key in the first method and the value in the second.

Comment: It is really a bad duplicate, but really bad concerning the OP question.

Comment: @davidxxx I agree. Reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Your `put()` method is not atomic. Try this instead:

```
public String put(String value) {
    return cache.computeIfAbsent(value, v -> someRandomString());
}
```

Comment: The `get()` method is not atomic, either.

Comment: @JohnBollinger With respect to what?

Comment: @JohnBollinger  but it will not break the map state as `ConcurrentHashMap` is used. Only not updated value could be displayed in `get()`. It is the main reason to use `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is - how to make proper synchronisation in case of
>   singleton and many threads calling the service.

The scope of your synchronization needs to cover whole *logical* operations, which in this case are much broader than individual method invocations on the internal `Map`.  As such, you don't actually get anything useful from using `ConcurrentHashMap` or a synchronized `Map` implementation, because the scope of the critical regions they provide is not broad enough.

For your particular example, with only the `put()` and `get()` methods presented, the simplest approach would be to simply declare each method `synchronized`.  And in that case, you can use a plain `HashMap` internally.  For example,

```
public synchronized String put(String key) {
    // ...
}

public synchronized String get(String key) {
    // ...
}
```

This assumes that indeed there is only one instance of the class.  If there were more than one, then synchronizing the methods would not be sufficient.  Presumably, however, each instance would then want its own map, so changing `cache` to an instance variable would also be needed too, and that would resolve the problem together with the synchronization.  Personally, I never would have made `cache` static in the first place.

Comment: If you switch to `HashMap` you need to synchronize `get()` as well.

Comment: Yes, @k5_, do you read "declare ***each*** method `synchronized`" differently?  But I have updated to better highlight the point.

Comment: Sorry missed that.

Comment: This isn't reliable as long as `cache` is static. Though it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: @shmosel, It will work fine if the instance is indeed a singleton, as the OP asserts.  You're right, though, that the point bears some attention.